# form sql to return bool to c#

Tags: c#, sql

what's the best way to form my sql so it will return a bool into a c# variable? Or is just easier to inspect the scalar value on the return of an .ExecuteScalar function?

Basically, want to know if row exists or not.

```
select COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='Customers' 
AND
COLUMN_NAME = 'birthdate'
AND
DATA_TYPE = 'datetime'
```

for example, if the row exists above return true.

Comment: Does [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/57470d82-d375-4f90-bf71-2b24e6237fe1) help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a CASE check on the result of the COUNT() to force 0 or 1:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsColumPresent
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='Customers' 
AND
COLUMN_NAME = 'birthdate'
AND
DATA_TYPE = 'datetime'
```

This will return 0 or 1

Comment: good, but you should also wrap the entire case block in

    cast(... as bit)

otherwise, it will return the 1 or 0 as an integer, not as a boolean

Comment: @CDJorgensen C# will read a 0 or 1 directly into a bool w/o any problem.